# Why doesn't this generic with super/extends work?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class X<T> implements Future<T> {

    public void addListener(Consumer<? extends Future<? super T>> listener) {
      listener.accept(this);
    }

  }
```

It complains that the capture type cannot be applied

Comment: Because you allow a `Consumer` working on a more "precise" type than `Future` which doesn't necessarily has to be `X`.

Comment: Thanks @lzruo. I was looking for a way to achieve this properly. Is there a way to do that? Currently, I have to use "uncheck" to perform a call and bypass generic type check instead.

Comment: @Nat well, `Consumer<Future<T>>`, `Consumer<Future<? super T>>` or `Consumer<? super Future<? super T>>` would work. Don't bypass type checking, it's rightly telling you there's a problem.